# Filtering Tables in R-markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is there simple a way, to filter a table in r? Something like this:

```
#list all cars with 6 cylinders
kable(mtcars, where(cyl="6"))
```

Comment: filter data before passing to kable `knitr::kable(subset(mtcars, cyl == 6))`. `knitr::kable` output is latex, html and other formats. It might be possible to filter them, however I wouldn't recommend that. `kable` was created for data display, not munging.

Comment: if the output is HTMl you can use `DT` package with filter extension to do dynamic filter inside the markdown

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
  filter(cyl=="6") %>%  
  kable()
```